# Why exporting duplicated object creates different results?

Tags: inkscape, rasterization

I have a fairly simple drawing in InkScape:

[image]

These are 3 equivalent paths, copied from the first one.

Line weight is 1pt.

When exporting this image, it results 3 different shapes:

[image]

If we look closely the bottom two blacks (especially their bottom lines):

[image]

I have tried first with default export settings, and then I tried finetuning it:

[image]

What should I do to get better (closer to original) results?

Comment: Your not exactly hitting the pixel grid

Comment: Hm, and how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pixel perfect renders are a little tricky in Inkscape. It may be more trouble than it's worth to be honest. It's probably better to use a raster image editor if your intention is to output pixel perfect raster images.

Anyway, it is possible.

1. In the document setup change all the units to pixels, and add a 1 pixel grid.  In the snapping controls, make sure to enable snapping and snap to grid.
2. Draw your shapes on the grid. Don't add any 1px strokes, or they won't line up with the grid. If you must use strokes, then be sure to set the width at 2px. You can't have half a pixel.
3. When exporting as raster be sure to set the ppi to 96, otherwise it will set 72 by default which will just mess everything up.

Here's an example of a pixel perfect render from Inskcape, starting with the document showing the grid

[image]

Here's the output settings

[image]

And here's the result zoomed in

[image]

Comment: Why 96 DPI is recommended? (For example against higher ones like 300?)

Comment: If you export at 300 ppi, then you won't really need pixel perfect designs. It's perfectly possible to export at 300ppi if you want to. However, if you want a small px image, which I assumed is what you want from your example image, then use 96ppi setting. It's basically Inkscapes default ppi - although Inkscape has no actual ppi because it's a vector image editor.  It's unfortunate that the raster export dialog defaults to 72ppi, maybe something the developers need to address. A slight bug/annoynace.